# Get an internal array of json response and create a list of objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I wanted to know if there is a way to create a list of "community" objects from an array "data" within this json:

```
    {
    "update_date": "2019.01",
    "size": 19,
    "data": [
            {
                    "CCOM": "01",
                    "COM": "ANLALUCÍA"
            },
            {
                    "CCOM": "02",
                    "COM": "ARAGÓN"
            },
            {
                    "CCOM": "03",
                    "COM": "PRINCIPADO DE ASTURIAS"
            },

    ],
    "warning": "Sandbox mode is turned on"
   }
```

Right now I do it as follows:

```
    @Data
    public class CommunityInfoResponse {

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<Community> communitys;

   }
```

---

```
    @Data
    @JsonIgnoreProperties
    public class Community{

    @JsonProperty("CCOM")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("COM")
    private String name;

    }
```

---

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<Community> comunidades = resTemplate.getForObject(API_key, CommunityInfoResponse.class).getCommunitys();
```

This works correctly, but my question is, if there is a way to avoid creating the complete structure and to be able to ignore the CommunityInfoResponse class?

Comment: your `CommunityInfoResponse` is not complete, you don't have `update_date` and `size` fields. About your question: what do you want to achieve? `CommunityInfoResponse` is your main Json class, why you don't want to create it? how then you want to deserealize that json?

Comment: Hi thanks, I already know that those two properties are missing but i want to know if I can pass that json using only one class like "community"

Comment: no, you cant. Jackson maps the fields of a JSON to the equal fields in a Java object by matching the names of the JSON fields and fields from your class without "get" and "set" (you have to have getters and setters in your serialization classes). That means that you should have appropriate structure that describes your Json. In other words you can't simplify that just by removing some of the class.